# Building application with PWA

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I have problem with situaton:

- when I use the command `ng serve --prod` to Service Worker is registered
- when I use the command `ng build --prod` to Service Worker is NOT registered. Missing files in dist

  - files `ngsw`

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool?

Comment: @Mathias No, Localhost is only HTTP

Comment: Show us your code how you register your service worker in your module

Comment: Are you registering your service worker in your app?

Answer (score 2):

Angular `ng serve` does not work with service worker.
You need to do a prod build and then serve the application from the `/dist` folder. You can use any web server you prefer: npm http-server or the [web server as Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb). This way you can test the service worker locally.

You can have a look at [this article](https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular), where I explain step by step how to create a PWA with Angular.

The article also refers to a Github Project with a running Angular PWA app, that you can use as starting point or to compare it with your code.